# Trouble with simple While and For loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

I am having some trouble with the below sample of code, please bear with me, still a beginner

```
var currentGen = 1;
var totalGen = 19;
var totalMW = 0;

totalMW = 62;
while (currentGen <= 4){
//Add 62 to the number of generators, beginning with Generator #1
console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 62 MW, for a total of " +    totalMW + " MW!");
totalMW = totalMW + 62;
currentGen++;
}

for (var currentGen = 5; currentGen <= totalGen; currentGen++){
//add 124 to generators #5 - 19
console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 124 MW, for a total of " +  totalMW + " MW!");
totalMW = totalMW + 124;
}
```

When printing Gen 5, it prints

> "Generator #5 is on, adding 124 MW, for a total of 310 MW!"

But I need it to add 124 onward from line 4, but it adds 64 instead of 124 to Gen 5. 



What am I missing? Should I be doing the calculation before the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var currentGen = 1;
var totalGen = 19;
var totalMW = 0;

while (currentGen <= 4){
//Add 62 to the number of generators, beginning with Generator #1
totalMW = totalMW + 62;
console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 62 MW, for a total of " +    totalMW + " MW!");
currentGen++;
}

for (var currentGen = 5; currentGen <= totalGen; currentGen++){
//add 124 to generators #5 - 19
totalMW = totalMW + 124;
console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 124 MW, for a total of " +  totalMW + " MW!");
}
```

This way you start with zero and perform all additions within the loop. Previously you were setting `totalMW` to 62 *before* the first loop, then incrementing the total again inside the loop - so after the first four iterations you had set to 62 (effectively one increment for Generator 1) and then incremented a further four times giving a total of five increments instead of four.

Comment: I was setting it to 62 because I need it to start from 62, as if the first generator was to power on and provide 62W. The example I'm givin has var totalMW starting at 0, so I altered it that way.

Comment: Look at my code - I have moved `totalMW = totalMW + 62;` to *before* the logging line. This means that `totalMW` (set to zero before the loop) will be 62 when the first line is logged, which is what you want.

Comment: Yea I understand that, I swore I tried that, but I guess I only did it in one of the loops. That was it. Thank you!. DIdn't mean to waste your time.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]:

```
while (currentGen < 4){
//Add 62 to the number of generators, beginning with Generator #1
console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 62 MW, for a total of " +    totalMW + " MW!");
totalMW = totalMW + 62;
currentGen++;
}

for (var currentGen = 4; currentGen <= totalGen; currentGen++){
//add 124 to generators #5 - 19
console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 124 MW, for a total of " +  totalMW + " MW!");
totalMW = totalMW + 124;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: This removes the entry for generator 4, tried this one.

Comment: He says:
"But I need it to add 124 onward from line 4, but it adds 64 instead of 124 to Gen 5"
So logically, I guess this is what he wants!

Comment: The initial value should be 62 :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/7nMBz/6/):

Use

```
while (currentGen <= 4){
//Add 62 to the number of generators, beginning with Generator #1
console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 62 MW, for a total of " +    totalMW + " MW!");
if(currentGen== 4) break;
totalMW = totalMW + 62;
currentGen++;
}

for (var currentGen = 5; currentGen <= totalGen; currentGen++){
//add 124 to generators #5 - 19
 totalMW = totalMW + 124;
console.log("Generator #" + currentGen + " is on, adding 124 MW, for a total of " +  totalMW + " MW!");

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work - it prints for 20 generators (0 to 19) instead of 19.